# Python class inheritance - using super() and __str__

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying out some stuff using inheritance with classes in Python 3.4. In the code below, I use the `super()` call to return the `__str__` from the parent class. Is it correct coding practice to save the information returned by the parent class method in a variable, concatenate the `__str__` from the child class to that of the parent class, and return like I did twice below?

Also, what would be best coding practice to convert such output to a string? Would it be better to

1. Do this also in the parent class.
2. Also in the child class.
3. When printing - in this case - `Director` or `Manager`?

---

```
class Employee:
   def __init__(self, name, salary, position):
      self._name = name
      self._salary = salary
      self._position = position

   def __str__(self):
      return str(self._name) + ' ' + str(self._salary) + ' ' + str(self._position)

class Director(Employee):
   def __init__(self, name, salary, position, mngteam):
      super().__init__(name, salary, position)
      self.managementteam = mngteam

   def __str__(self):
      st = super().__str__() # IS THIS GOOD CODING PRACTICE?
      st += ' ' + str(self.managementteam)
      return st

class Manager(Employee):
   def __init__(self, name, salary, position, supervises):
      super().__init__(name, salary, position)
      self.supervises = supervises

   def __str__(self):
      st = super().__str__() # IS THIS GOOD CODING PRACTICE?
      st += ' ' + str(self.supervises)
      return st

d = Director('DirMax', 100000, 'Director', 5)
print(d)
m = Manager('ManSam', 50000, 'Manager', 10)
print(m)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general, calling the parent class implementation, keeping the result and then processing it is perfectly acceptable OOP practice. However, there *is* a problem with your string handling; concatenation (`+`) is not the most efficient way of doing things (e.g. `a + b + c` becomes `(a + b) + c`, creating intermediate strings that aren't needed). Instead, when implementing `__str__` and `__repr__`, you can use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), for example:

```
class Employee:

   ...

   def __str__(self):
      return '{0._name!s} {0._salary!s} {0._position!s}'.format(self)


class Director(Employee):

   ...

   def __str__(self):
      return '{0} {1.managementteam}'.format(super().__str__(), self)
```

---

You aren't entirely compliant with [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/); for example, `managementteam`/`mngteam` should really be `management_team`. Additionally, you have an odd mix of *private-by-convention* (leading underscore, e.g. `_salary`) and *public* (no leading underscore, e.g. `supervises`) instance attributes - why? Should these be protected? Should the instance be immutable? Some [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) would be nice, too.

---

I would be inclined to add some validation of inputs - for example, if `salary` should always be a positive integer, you could add checking for that. One way to do that is in `__init__`, but a more thorough approach is with a *property*:

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, ..., salary, ...):
        ...
        self.salary = salary  # note assignment to salary not _salary
        ...

    ...

    @property
    def salary(self):
        return self._salary

    @salary.setter
    def salary(self, new_salary):
        if new_salary < 0:
            raise ValueError('salary must be positive')
        self._salary = new_salary
```

Comment: Great comment jonrsharpe! Thanks! I will read more about properties etc. For now, why would it be a bad habit to name class attributes with a preceding underscore? Doesn't this mean that this attribute should be treated as private?

Comment: @tufyjhkvh yes, the leading underscore means *private-by-convention*. But it's not clear from this code *why* they should be private (again, docstrings would be handy!) Should they be read-only, for example (this can also be achieved with a property)?

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe. I've read some documentation regarding your comment. Your comment was very helpful, thanks! Still one remaining question, what is the property decorator for? I haven't been able to find much useful documentation about this.. Thanks! :)

Comment: It's a way to customise access to specific attributes; see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17330273/3001761